# Ajax Post Request to TastyPie Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, tastypie

I am having an issue with the Django TastyPie API and creating a post request in JQuery. The curl request:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"created":"1983-01-30 09:20","author":"me","body":"meh", "post":"/api/v1/entry/1/"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comment/
```

Works totally fine. However, when I try to use the jquery ajax request in the following code. It does absolutely nothing. I have already included XS-Sharing in my settings. I checked in the error console. The JSON for data comes our correctly formatted. It seems to get stuck at OPTIONS with the url provided but I'm not entirely sure. Here's my code:

The api

```
    class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'pub_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'lte', 'gte', 'gt'],
        }


class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    post = fields.ForeignKey(EntryResource, 'post')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comment'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

MODEL

```
    class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # For automatic slug generation.
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)[:50]
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Entry)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("%s: %s" % (self.post, self.body[:60]))


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["post"]
```

HTML

```
    <form id="add_comment" action="{% url blogsite.views.post post.pk%}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div id="cform">
        Name: {{ form.author }}
        <p>{{ form.body|linebreaks }}</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="post" value= "{{post.pk}}">
    </div>
    <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

AND THE JS FILE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add_comment').submit(function() {
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "created": "1993-01-31 09:18",
    "author": $("#id_author").val(),
    "body": $("#id_body").val(),
    "post": "api/v1/entry/"+ $("#post").val() + "/"
  });
  console.log(data);
  console.log("hello");
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comment/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log("There was an error processing" + data);
      }
  });
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help you can give. I'm running out of ideas as to what could be the problem.

Comment: Your form has a csrf_token and you don't include it in your ajax request, but then your curl request doesn't include it either. It's definitely not throwing a 403 error?

Comment: I don't think TastyPie resources respect the CSRF token. Since this is bound to a form submit event, you may have to `preventDefault` on the event object so you don't get a page load before the ajax request finishes. Does Chrome's Network panel offer any help? Do the headers there look correct, etc.?  Is a request made at all?

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem, it wasn't with the CSRF because I allow XS_sharing, with tastypie. The preventdefault was part of the problem, but the real problem was that the json url was missing a forward slash before the /api/v1/comment/, with that and preventDefault the problem was fixed.