# How to create multiple objects with django tastypie via Ajax using the PATCH method?

Tags: ajax, django, tastypie

Trying to create multiple objects with django tastypie using Jquery and its failing alerts `Not connect` as specified in the code below. But performing a request with curl using the same data(`sent_data`) am passing to ajax, works perfectly.

```
sent_data = {"objects":[{"shopping_id":"#3Q^9%LF728N!9*840H(NEAH2L%J8$3H2J35(ZI@32MSA!S@RD%D3#PQG9^2#*J69S4&7IJX)POV$PYQ70817P2C!6OEPA%*$WR7","quantity":"3","option":"/api/v1/option/2/","item":"/api/v1/item/1/","created_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","modified_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","toppings_and_extras":["/api/v1/topping/1/","/api/v1/topping/2/"]},{"shopping_id":"#3Q^9%LF728N!9*840H(NEAH2L%J8$3H2J35(ZI@32MSA!S@RD%D3#PQG9^2#*J69S4&7IJX)POV$PYQ70817P2C!6OEPA%*$WR7","quantity":"3","option":"/api/v1/option/2/","item":"/api/v1/item/1/","created_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","modified_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","toppings_and_extras":["/api/v1/topping/1/","/api/v1/topping/2/"]}]};

$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/order/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:sent_data,
        headers:{'X-HTTP-Method-Override':'PATCH'},
        dataType:'json',
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            alert("POST request made");

        },
        error: function(jqXHR,exception){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

Looking at [django-tastypie PATCH gives me a "400 (Bad Request)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868908/django-tastypie-patch-gives-me-a-400-bad-request) and [Ajax Post Request to TastyPie Doesn't Do Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637724/ajax-post-request-to-tastypie-doesnt-do-anything,i) figured since i am trying to make a bulk operation as mentioned in the docs, i had to use 'PATCH' method, which i did by providing a X-HTTP-Method-Override header but all on vain. What Could i have missed?

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, i figured problem was that i was not setting a header for the 'CSRFToken' in the form, this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/henriquea/9214393) helped me figure it out. So the working request looks this,

```
sent_data = JSON.stringify({"objects":[{"shopping_id":"#3Q^9%LF728N!9*840H(NEAH2L%J8$3H2J35(ZI@32MSA!S@RD%D3#PQG9^2#*J69S4&7IJX)POV$PYQ70817P2C!6OEPA%*$WR7","quantity":"3","option":"/api/v1/option/2/","item":"/api/v1/item/1/","created_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","modified_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","toppings_and_extras":["/api/v1/topping/1/","/api/v1/topping/2/"]},{"shopping_id":"#3Q^9%LF728N!9*840H(NEAH2L%J8$3H2J35(ZI@32MSA!S@RD%D3#PQG9^2#*J69S4&7IJX)POV$PYQ70817P2C!6OEPA%*$WR7","quantity":"3","option":"/api/v1/option/2/","item":"/api/v1/item/1/","created_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","modified_by":"/api/v1/user/-1/","toppings_and_extras":["/api/v1/topping/1/","/api/v1/topping/2/"]}]});

$.ajax({
        url:'/api/v1/order/?format=json',
        accepts:'application/json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers:{
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override':'PATCH'
        },
        method:'POST',
        data:sent_data,
        beforeSend:function(jqXHR,settings){
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken',$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val())
        },
        dataType:'json',
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            alert("damn posted");

        },
        error: function(jqXHR,exception){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also notice i passed to a JSON.stringify() method.